# apci pcc probe failed after upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04

Tags: 14.04, 15.04

I had a update notification so I accepted it and once it finished the process it restarted. The first message on the screen was this:

```
1.323856 acpi pcc probe failed
Starting version 219
```

I can see login screen but when I put my password in it never makes it to the desktop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is \[ 0.4486641 ACPI PCC probe failed\] starting version 219?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/603398/what-is-0-4486641-acpi-pcc-probe-failed-starting-version-219)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)

Answer (score 0):

From this topic:
https://askubuntu.com/a/605455/101797

Try [this solution](http://life.wamari.com/2015/03/16/fixing-starting-version-219-bug-in-kubuntu-15-04-vivid-vervet-beta/):

> 1. Restart your computer, as it boots up hold the Shift key so as to
>      get grub boot options.
> 2. Select Advanced Options from the grub menu and boot into the system.
> 3. Enter your login details and run the commands below
>
> Commands:

```
sudo systemctl enable sddm.service -f
sudo reboot
```

> After this your computer should be able to boot up normally.

Comment: When you find an answer on another question, please flag this one as a Duplicate. We like to combine them. If you can't flag, please avoid answering, and when you can comment do that!

Comment: Got `Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)` `Error  to execute operation: No such file or directory`.
And now, what I have to do?