# Can't boot Ubuntu live cd

Tags: kubuntu, live-usb, acpi

For some reason i can't boot Ubuntu live cd on my desktop pc while installation media works perfectly on laptop. I'm getting this error :[image: ubuntu error]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer, is more like a helping hand I can give you. I wonted to use the "comment" section for this, but I need more characters than the standard 12.

Well, I admit that personally I haven't encountered any such error. None that I remember of. So I can't give you any advice from my own experience. But I did a search on your error and turned up that you have some USB-related malfunction.

Here are several links where I think you could find an answer to your specific problem.

[Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed - a question posted on Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)

The answers to this specific question lead to other links that might give you the answer.

In case none helps, search for "acpi pc probe failed".

[[SOLVED] device descriptor read/64, error -71 - USB problem - a thread on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=797789)

It is marked as "solved", but in case it doesn't help, then search for "usb 4-2 device descriptor read/64"

[usbhid can't find input interrupt endpoint - a question posted on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116615/usbhid-cant-find-input-interrupt-endpoint)

If this doesn't help, then search for "couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint".

This is how I found these links.