# Ubuntu Host in VirtualBox has long delays before startup

Tags: virtualbox, performance, 15.04

I run Ubuntu in virtualbox on a windows 8.1 host. After some updates of the guest, it started to have lags/delays before it starts. It also shows some warnings. After it starts, everything is fast. After some major updates (I now run ubuntu 15.04) the got extremely long (like 1 min).
The machine is quite powerful (Core i7, 16GB ram, ssd), so after it starts to boot, it loads completely in 2 seconds. The warnings:

```
[     0.595143] ACPI PCC probe failed.
starting version 219
[     6.980975] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.0: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
[     7.062037] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
```

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Did you install guest additions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)