# What does "ACPI PPC Probe failed Starting version 219 " mean exactly?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.04, acpi

I've recently installed Xubuntu 15.04 on my desktop

The video playback was kinda slow and buggy so I installed the nvidia drivers (the gpu is an onboard 7025)

As some people, I get the "ACPI PPC Probe ..." message, but after 20 seconds or so, the system boots just fine, also the video playback is fine and there doesn't seem to be any graphic issues

My question is: Should I be worried about that message popping every time I boot? and what does it exactly means?

I didn't found any answers to that, just workarounds for people who can't pass the message

Comment: same issue for me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is **harmless**. In fact it is 2 messages

**First**:

```
ACPI PCC Probe failed
```

It is a new built-in feature of the 3.19 kernel. It just states that it did not found some *PCC* software or hardware. I don't know much about it.

**Second**:

```
Starting version 219
```

This is a message from *systemd*, stating it is starting. `219` is the `systemd` version.

You can safely ignore them.

Comment: But my system doesn't boot at all after the "harmless" messages...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem which doesn't require any workaround. In the end I have the Nvidia driver.

My configuration is: Xubuntu 15.04, with a GeForce 960 GPU.

I get the same message than you after installing Nvidia driver through apt-get. So here is my solution:

1. Go to [Cuda Downloads](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) and download the Runfile Installer you need for your distribution.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and log to your account.
3. Stop all graphics: `sudo service lightdm stop` (or `sudo service dm stop`).
4. Purge all Nvidia stuff: `sudo apt-get remove-purge nvidia-*`.
5. Go where you put the Runfile, make it executable and run it with the following commands:

   ```
   chmod u+x cuda_7.*_linux.run
   sudo ./cuda_7.*_linux.run
   ```
6. Follow the instruction, you may not want to install the Cuda toolkit or driver it is up to you I guess. (I wanted them so I installed them).
7. Configure the X server: `sudo nvidia-xconfig`.
8. reboot: `sudo reboot`.