# Start problem in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: acpi, systemd-logind

I have this problem with my pc:

```
[    0.545187]ACPI PCC PROBE FAILED. STARTING VERSION 219
[    240.096017] INFO: task systemd-udev:376 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[    240.096060] Not tainted 3.19.0-15-generic #15-ubuntu
[    240.096097]"echo 0> /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.............
```

Well, the message duplicates, and the OS doesn't start, so I had to reboot my pc. However the problem appears periodically, I hope someone can help with this.

Comment: What is this "SO" that doesn't start?

Comment: Operative system, sorry, I speak spanish, my english is bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to boot using the `nomodeset` option. To do this:

1. Restart your computer and select Advanced Options from the grub menu
2. Highlight the kernel that you want to boot into and press `e` to edit it.
3. Find the line that says `"quiet splash"` and replace it with:

> "quiet splash nomodeset"

4. press F10 to boot.

Is it working?

Comment: Ok, it still showing me the message, but an error appears with my bluetooth, it's not a problem, because the system start up, but it doesn't save the command "nomodeset" once restart the pc

Comment: Well, the system starts, but, when I restart my pc, the nomodeset erases, so, I don't know why it happends. The first time I tried it, it works well, but when I restart the pc the message appears again..............there exists any method to erase or disable the PCC?

Comment: make this exact change in the `etc/default/grub` file. Save it and run `sudo update-grub` and you will not have to do this every time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this is the last message you see and that the problem is something completely unrelated.

> So it looks like you build the PCC mailbox driver which is new in
>   3.19-rc and that driver fails to load, because it doesn't find hardware to work with.
>
> The message is harmless, but it also is not useful. The driver in
>   question seems to be overly verbose to me in general.

From [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)

> PCC (Platform Communication Channel) is a recent ACPI 5.0 addition.
>   The driver does not find a PCC communications mailbox and just exits
>   with that error message. It is not something to worry about, most
>   machines don't have an ACPI PCCT table and they don't use this
>   mechanism. References: ACPI specification Chapter 14.0 "Platform
>   Communications Channel" Linux source: drivers/mailbox/pcc.c

From https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1430625

Also: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92551