# Can't boot after installing Ubuntu 15.04 message [3.877375] ACPI PCC probe failed.starting version 219.error opening USB device 'descriptors' file

Tags: boot, usb

Can't boot after installing Ubuntu 15.04 message:

```
[3.877375] ACPI PCC probe failed. starting version 219. error opening USB device 'descriptors' file.
```

I managed to boot in safe mode. My laptop is Toshiba Satellite C600-P4012. Intel Pentium T4500. Intel GL40 chipset. Intel HD Graphics.In "About Computer" earlier it showed Intel HD Graphics, instead it is now showing Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits).Please help.

Comment: Did you try the answer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/622302/start-problem-in-ubuntu-15-04) question?

Comment: Please post ALL of the dmesg output. This message is not likely related to why you cannot boot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)