# Ubuntu Upgrade to 15.04 Boot Problems, with linux-headers- 3.19.0-17(3.19.0-17.17) update

Tags: 15.04

Updated to 15.04, Im using sddm display manager and it shows error: /dev/sdb: No medium found with starting version 219. Some of the features on recovery mode show ERROR GETTING AUTHORITY. Once the computer suspends it will not boot again, I have to restart the computer and enter through recovery mode with normally start. This started to happen when i did an update packages were: linux-headers- 3.19.0-17(3.19.0-17.17). Any solutions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.I just removed my official `nvidia` driver and switched back to my `nouveau` driver using the recovery mode.But this isn't a driver which gives you the acceleration you need.If you are not using an `nvidia` graphics card don't do what I am saying in this post.This was what I have done to switch back to `nouveau`.

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Then reboot.

Stop sddm using `service`.

I had blacklisted my `nouveau`.
So, removed the file which I created to blacklist.

After a reboot again I started my display manager.

But from the next time it took a lot of time to load.
It was the nvidia driver which bugged me.
If you also have the same problem look into [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed).
Hope this is helpful.