# Won't boot, ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: boot, acpi

After updating, my desktop machine will no longer boot. It shows the message `ACPI PCC probe failed, starting version 219` and then stops in with a command prompt and some text about it being in Emergency Mode.

There are already numerous questions on this, but only [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed) appears to have an answer. The accepted and upvoted answer does not actually give a solution; it says that the message is harmless and can be ignored.

Since my PC will no longer boot, I am finding it difficult to ignore. What do I need to do?

**Edit**:
There is a list of startup tasks, all showing '**OK**', the last being `Show Plymouth Boot Screen...`

And below that is the `Welcome to emergency mode!` prompt.

Viewing the system logs with `journalctl -xb` gives a vast amount of output - what should I be looking for?

The output of `systemctl --failed` is

```
âùÅ home-carl-Music.mount  loaded failed failed /home/carl/Music
```

and my other NFS shares are also listed.

I have edited them out of `/etc/fstab` and the machine now boots.

Comment: You ignored the wrong message. You can ignore "ACPI PCC probe failed ..." but what is after that is mroe relevant. What is it ? How have you updated yur machine ?

Comment: @solsTiCe Updating was via the Update Manager. I've edited the post with what comes after the ACPI PCC probe message.

Comment: What is the output of `systemctl --failed` ?

Comment: @solsTiCe My NFS shares were causing the issue. See edit. Thank you for your help.  I will ask a new question about the NFS problem.