# Hybrid Nvidia and Intel cards, bumblebee optirun not working and OpenGL not being Intel

Tags: drivers, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, opengl

I have been fighting with the installation and correct usage of my Nvidia GTX960M together with an Intel i7-4720M CPU on Ubuntu 15.04.

I have followed lots of links on this website, on ubuntu wiki and on ubuntuforums (I will not add all the links here, since it's too much). At the beginning I had even problems with black screen after boot or no rebooting at all. After using proprietary drivers and fixing the "nomodeset" line in GRUB everything works fine, but still I'm not satisfied, since apparently some people have managed to make it work. I just find that some solutions are either too old or they contradict themselves and lead to nothing. By trying all these things, at some point I also solved the [ACPI PCC probe failed problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed), I don't know how.

After following all the instructions to install [Bumblebee](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Install-and-usage), checking other [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu) and following the [troubleshooting](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting#bumblebeed-module-nvidia-is-not-found) and even trying to edit my /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf in all suggested ways, I still get messages like:

```
$ optirun glxspheres
[ 1844.581142] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 1844.581214] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

If I change some of my lines in /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf I get other different errors.

Besides this, I see that my OpenGL renderer is not Intel:

```
glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
```

And I get very low performance and flickering when trying to work with visualization software. (I also see strange coloured pixels and flickering after the splash boot screen in Ubuntu).

I also have no support for Unity3D and my OpenGL is software rendered:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --print
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.5.2

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

I have already tried to do stuff like:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel  libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

But also unsuccessfully...

I add here some extra information on my devices.

```
lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core    Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0416] (rev 06)   (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:139b] (rev a2)



$ dpkg -l nvidia-\* | grep '^ii'
ii  nvidia-346              346.59-0ubuntu1  amd64        NVIDIA binary  driver - version 346.59
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-346   346.59-0ubuntu1  amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime            0.8.1            amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings         346.59-0ubuntu1  amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Thanks for any help!!