# Resulution problem after installing NVIDIA binary driver (v346.96)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution

The screen is now 1024x768 (4:3) resolution, and I can't change that, when I turn on my computer a boot error shows up, maybe this two problems are matches, but I'm not too sure...

(ACPI PCC probe failed)

Than my computer turn on with this low res. and I can't even change it on the NVIDIA settings, because when I change the "ViewPortIn" to 1920x1080, the panning change, but that's not a problem, the "ViewPortOut" not changes, and that's the problem, first I tried to change it manually, but when I press to a another box, or I hit apply than it change back the numbers again, so I have no idea how to fix this problem.

(I used X.Org X server driver, and that problem wasn't there, I could run the screen in 1920x1080!)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: Does this command work ? notice how it is the commands for nvidia-settings  `nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080, ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0, Panning 1920x1080}"`

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is add the resolution using `xrandr` - [this](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html) is a good guide. You would then need to add the `xrandr` configurations to a startup file, so that you'll get your desired resolution upon reboot/startup:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
  sudo xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080_60.00
  xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
  ```
- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**OR** you can go the easy way and use a program that does the above for you -  [ResolutionX.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx)

Comment: How can I make the script executable with chmod +x xrandr.sh

Comment: @BenceDomokos enter that into the terminal