# (Ubuntu 14.04 ACPI PCC Probe Failed) Please Help!

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to fresh install Ubuntu 14.04 from a DVD. I boot from the DVD only to come to a black screen saying ACPI PCC Probe Failed, and it will not go anywhere from there.

I have to manually shut off my pc from the switch in the back for it to actually shut down, because my pc freezes at that point. Is it because I'm trying to install it from a hdd that also has windows 7 ultimate 64 bit on it also?

Comment: What is your video adapter?

Comment: This may be a duplicate so check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed Or, more specifically, this particular answer may be what you're looking for: http://askubuntu.com/a/678368/453950 - Keep us updated so someone can flag as a duplicate if needed. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried everything that thread had to offer, but nothing worked. I took a picture of the screen where it said ACPI PCC Probe Failed where you can see here http://i1028.photobucket.com/albums/y350/Alaskanrff/20151015_2308541_zpsroee4nk5.jpg . I hope someone can see what's wrong here because as of right now I am a total noob to linux and it's requirements.