# Fault [ 0.587243 ] etc. ? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: segmentation-fault

Just before Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS starts up a black screen appears with the text:

```
[ 0.587243 ] ACPI PCC Probe failed.
```

It is a notebook with UEFI Bios 2013.
How can I solve this problem please?

Comment: what happen next? Did the PC freeze? It looks like a warning...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)

Answer (score -1):

Already asked and answered I believe... http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.power-management.general/56400 Unless someone knows different.

But it seems to be an apparently harmless message that doesn't alter whether your system is working properly. Mine does exactly the same thing so unless your system has some other problem you haven't explained it's probably not worth worrying about

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately too difficult for me...

Comment: In other words it's an apparently harmless message that doesn't alter whether your system is working properly. Mine does exactly the same thing so unless your system has some other problem you haven't explained it's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: Put that in your answer.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...
(Oh, and make it easier for the newbies while you're at it)  **;-)**