# Installing CUDA purges previous NVIDIA driver installation

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda

I just finished installing CUDA on my system following these [instructions](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) and found out that the installation changed the NVIDIA driver being used on my machine from version `352.55` to version `352.39`, as you can see below:

[image: version of NVIDIA drivers is 352.39]

I probably wouldn't have even noticed it if I hadn't [installed](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2015/09/how-to-install-nvidia-352-41-stable-graphics-drivers-in-linux.html) the driver version `352.55` to avoid the following two errors:

- [`ACPI PCC Probe Failed`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed)
- [`snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: failed to add i915 component master (-19)`]

that pop-up on any other driver I installed.

I have 2 questions:

1. During CUDA installation, is there a way to specify **NOT** to change the currently installed NVIDIA drivers?
2. If I purge driver `352.39` and reinstall `352.55` is this going to mess up my system / CUDA installation?

My system: `Linux vega 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: 1. You may want to ask someone from Nvidia, if such an option is available in the installer. 2. Again, you should ask Nvidia if other driver versions are allowed.

Comment: After you install driver, make sure to install nvidia-modprobe and then install CUDA via deb file from Nvidia for latest one. During install deselect installation of driver.

Comment: @ArupRoyChowdhury - Could you please write your comment in form of an answer? It'd be very useful! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is for standalone desktop with nvidia graphics. If you wish to retain your existing driver, download the 7.5 CUDA deb from nvidia, during install, deselect driver option otherwise your existing driver would get over written. Make sure to do the bash entries as described in the nvidia manual. if you have the driver installed, make sure to install nvidia-modprobe and reboot or else CUDA will not see your driver install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! A last doubt, how do you deselect driver option?

Comment: During install it will offer to install driver, select N.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear in the instructions that you linked to  that in order for CUDA to work there are tight restrictions on supported environments (see table 1 **Native Linux Distribution Support in CUDA 6.5** on page 2). Your kernel version is  3.19.0-25-generic while the requirements listed indicate 3.13 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I can only suggest that perhaps if you follow the strict requirements exactly you might get the results you desire. I cannot guarantee this however. If you find another solution please post your answer here so that others with the same problem can learn from your experience.