# Cant boot Ubuntu 15.10 ( not even the live version)

Tags: boot, usb, lubuntu, live-usb

Hi everyone ( sorry for my bad english), i own an Hp Stream 13 (2x1.6GHZ, 2GB RAM, 32GB SSD) with windows 10, and yesterday i have successfully installed Ubuntu 15.10 ( using a 4gb usb stick with Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.2). Everything was perfectly fine, i have used my netbook with ubuntu the whole day, but now it won't start anymore!
Long story short, i wanted to try the live version on lubuntu 15 so i used the same software (USB-Installer-1.9.6.2) from my other deskto pc with windows, to load the iso on the usb stick. Now i don't know what happened with my notebook, but the live versione of lubunt didn't started, and this message appeared:

```
>Ignoring BGRT: Ivalid status 0 (expected 1)
>ACPI PCC probe failed 
>sd:0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
>sd:0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write throught
>BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) build-in shell (ash)
>Enter 'help' for a list of build-in commands
>(initramfs) mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Invalid argument
>Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

screenshot of the full message:

[image]

Basically now i can't use my notebook because if i try to just turn it on it wont start, and if try the live ubuntu / lubunt from the usb-stick it wont start too. I have tried 2 different usb stick and tried to mount ubuntu ( v.15 and v.14) and lubuntu more than once but everytime i got the same message.

I'm desperate i don't know what to do, i hope i don't have crashed my notebook

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your BIOS looks like, but try to change a similar setting in yours as is detailed below. To enter your BIOS, I think you have to press ESC repeatedly.

(Copied from [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed))

"I [Solved] the problem by changing the motherboard settings. For my motherboard (access this at boot, not through Ubuntu) I went to Advanced > System Agent > Graphics > iPGU Multi-Monitor and set it to "enable." I left all of the other system agent graphics settings on auto. After that the boot and ACPI problems (including a shutdown hang, crashes, freezes, monitor shutdown) stopped.

Every motherboard vendor has its own settings. The problem seems to be a northbridge snafu between the onboard Intel graphics and the Nvidia card. So, it may takes several visits to your motherboard setup to find the right combination of settings that works for you. This problem was new to me under 15.04, and may be due to a change in how Ubuntu handles such graphics disputes.

(My motherboard is ASUS P8Z77-V LX LGA 1155 Intel Z77)"