# My computer freezes at startup *ERROR* rv770_set_sw_state failed

Tags: 14.04, boot, ati, suspend, freeze

My computer often totally freezes at startup. I have to reset computer. Some say that I could have problems with power supply. When operating system is loaded, it is operating normally.

This error is displayed on the screen while the operating system is loading:

```
[ 0.452876] ACPI PCC probe failed.
```

Occasionally my computer freezes even when I exit suspend mode. Displayed errors are:

```
[ 2634.651626] [drm:rv730_stop_dpm [radeon]] *ERROR* Could not force DPM to low
[ 2635.967635] [drm:rw770_dpm_set_power_state [radeon]] *ERROR* rv770_set_sw_state failed
```

Answer (score 0):

`ACPI PCC Probe faild` is probably a [harmless warning message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed).

`*ERROR* rv770_set_sw_state failed` is [bug #1319589](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1319589). Some comments there report that upgrading to kernel 4.4 helped, so try that. If you still have problems with a 4.4 kernel then ask upstream on the [open freedesktop.org bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=76130) or open a new bug report there.