# Boot Error [0.5554871] ACPI PPC probe failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

So I just installed Ubunutu 14.04.4 LTS onto my desktop computer. Everything was working fine and I did all the necessary updates, installed google chrome and tweaked some customization settings, and then restarted.

When I went to boot Ubuntu, I did so by manually selecting the boot device from the boot option because I had not yet set up the boot order in my BIOS. THe screen turned purple for a second and then gave me this error message:

```
[0.5554871] ACPI PPC probe failed
```

And I don't know how to fix this issue. All my google searches say it has to do with my Nvidia card but have no real fix for the problem.

Here are my specs

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte Z87-D3HP
CPU: Intel Core i7-4770k 3.5 GHz
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 760
```

Comment: Did you install drivers for Nvidia?

Comment: "[0.5554871] ACPI PPC probe failed" is a ---harmless notice---. Your problem is something else (and yes, it will probably be video card related as @Pilot6 asks). Dupe on the notice(!): http://askubuntu.com/a/584875/15811 Should be fixed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1524930 in 3.19.0-47.53.